# rsyslog Filtering Based on IP Address with Wildcards

Tags: logs, rsyslog

I have some syslog traffic being processed by rsyslog and I'd like to set up filters to store the logs based on the IP addresses of the source devices. I have a large number of devices and would prefer to avoid creating a rule for each device. The IP scheme is consistent enough that I would think I could handle everything with a single rule but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Here are a couple of (failed) examples of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
:FROMHOST, regex, "10\.[0-9]+\.1\.2" -/var/log/test.log
& ~
```

or

```
if ( re_match($fromhost-ip, '10\.[0-9]+\.1\.2') ) then { -/var/log/test.log }
& ~
```

Basically, the IP scheme for these devices will always be 10.*.1.2, where * is a 2 digit number corresponding to the location of the device.

Can someone give me an idea of where I'm going wrong with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was actually able to discover the solution on my own after finding a debug option for running rsyslog. Apparently, you can call rsyslogd directly from the console like so:

```
rsyslogd -d
```

Doing that will show a live stream of all rule parsing. After a **ton** of trial and error using this trick, I was able to determine that my filter rules were failing because several parts needed, not just escaped, but *double* escaped. This really surprised me.

Here is what my final rule looked like:

```
:fromhost-ip, regex, "10\\.[0-9]\\+\\.1\\.2" -/var/log/test.log
& ~
```

And here is the output for a couple of successful examples. Notice that the `+` has to show up here as escaped which is strange because no matches are found if you plug it into the official [rsyslog regex tester](http://www.rsyslog.com/regex/) this way:

```
Filter: check for property 'fromhost-ip' (value '10.1.1.2') regex '10\.[0-9]\+\.1\.2': TRUE

Filter: check for property 'fromhost-ip' (value '10.24.1.2') regex '10\.[0-9]\+\.1\.2': TRUE
```

In case anyone reading this some day is curious, here are some of my trial and error examples, most of which simply failed entirely:

```
Filter: check for property 'fromhost-ip' (value '10.1.1.2') regex '10.[0-9]+.1.2': FALSE

Filter: check for property 'fromhost-ip' (value '10.1.1.2') regex '^10.[0-9]+.1.2$': FALSE

Filter: check for property 'fromhost-ip' (value '10.1.1.2') regex '10\.[0-9]+\.1\.2': FALSE

Filter: check for property 'fromhost-ip' (value '10.1.1.2') regex '10\.1\.1\.2': TRUE

Filter: check for property 'fromhost-ip' (value '10.1.1.2') regex '10\.[0-9]\.1\.2': TRUE

Filter: check for property 'fromhost-ip' (value '10.1.1.2') regex '10\.[0-9]+\.1\.2': FALSE
```

Comment: Hi, no idea how you got this to work. I have RSYSLOG v8 and also the rsyslog regex checker always returns NO MATCH.